# RDS to Neptune DMS task translates all rows into a single vertex

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune, dms

I have a table in RDS defined as follows:

---

### | id | first_name | prime_faculty | etc...|

My GraphMappingConfig json is defined as follows:

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule_id": "1",
            "rule_name": "researcher_row_to_vertex",
            "table_name": "table_name",
            "vertex_definitions": [
                {
                    "vertex_id_template": "RESEARCHER_{id}",
                    "vertex_label": "researcher",
                    "vertex_definition_id": "1",
                    "vertex_properties": [
                        {
                            "property_name": "first_name",
                            "property_value_template": "{first_name}",
                            "property_value_type": "String"
                        },
                        {
                            "property_name": "prime_faculty",
                            "property_value_template": "{prime_faculty}",
                            "property_value_type": "String"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
      ]
}
```

however when the DMS tasks completes, the output I get from gremlin is a single vertex with all the property values defined in an array.

The query I used was `g.V().valueMap()`

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong with my graphmappingconfig?

The DMS task completes successfully and even says all the rows from the RDS database are loaded in, it just doesn't load it in the correct format.

Comment: Could you post output of g.V().id()? I think somehow RESEARCHER_{id} is not getting parsed correctly or the {id} field has same value for the table.

Comment: it shows up as: RESEARCHER_{id} so I assumed it hasn't been parsed correctly, I'll try using another row from our table

Comment: Yes you were right it couldn't parse the {id}, i used another field from our database that was also unique and it worked, is there a reason why the id's couldn't be parsed?

Comment: I dont know of a reason why id field wouldn't be parsed. are you projecting a view of the  table or whole table ? I think you can open a ticket with DMS to get to the root cause.